# Code feedback for python guessing game

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, while-loop, feedback

I am new to Python (and coding in general) and after about a week of reading "Thinking Like a Computer Scientist: Learning with Python" I decided to try and build a version the classic "guessing game".  I added some extra features such as counting the number of guesses the user takes, and playing against a simulated "computer" player to make the program slightly more interesting.  Also, the number of guesses the computer takes is based on the mean number of guesses needed to guess a number in a given range (which is logarithmic of base 2 for range n) and varies according to standard deviation.  Any feedback on the structure of my code or the way I generate the number of guesses the computer takes would be much appreciated!!!

Anywayyysss.... here is my code

```
import random


def get_number(level):                  #selects a random number in range depending on difficulty selected
    if level == "e":
        number = random.randint(1,20)
    if level == "m":
        number = random.randint(1,100)
    if level == "h":
        number = random.randint(1,1000)
    elif level != "e" and level != "m" and level != "h":
        print ("Invalid input!")
        get_number()
    return number


def select_level():                   #prompts the user to select a difficulty to play on
    level = str(input("Would you like to play on easy, medium, or hard? \n"
                      "Type 'e' for easy, 'm' for medium, or 'h' for hard!\n"))
    return level


def guess_number(level):        #function that prompts the user to guess within range depending on chosen difficulty
    if level == "e":
        guess = int(input("Guess a number between 1 and 20:\n"))
    if level == "m":
        guess = int(input("Guess a number between 1 and 100:\n"))
    if level == "h":
        guess = int(input("Guess a number between 1 and 1000:\n"))
    return guess


def check_guess(guess,number):         #processes the users guess and evaluates if it is too high, too low, or bang on
    if guess > number:
        print ("your guess is too high! Try again! \n")
    if guess < number:
        print ("your guess is too low! Try again! \n")
    if guess == number:
        print("\n{0} was the number!".format(number))


def com_num_guesses(level):          #function to get the number of guesses taken by the computer
    if level == "e":
        com_guesses = round(random.normalvariate(3.7,1.1))
    if level == "m":
        com_guesses = round(random.normalvariate(5.8,1.319))
    if level == "h":
        com_guesses = round(random.normalvariate(8.99,1.37474))
    print("The computer guessed the number in {0} guesses! Can you beat that?".format(com_guesses))
    return com_guesses


def mainloop():
    level = select_level()
    number = get_number(level)
    com_guesses = com_num_guesses(level)
    guess = guess_number(level)
    check_guess(guess,number)
    num_guesses = 1
    if guess == number:           #tells program what to do if first guess is correct
        print("You got it in {0} guesses.".format(num_guesses))
        if num_guesses == com_guesses:
            print("It took the computer {0} guesses too!\nIt's a tie!\n".format(com_guesses))
        if num_guesses > com_guesses:
            print("It took the computer {0} guesses.\nThe computer wins!\n".format((com_guesses)))
        if num_guesses < com_guesses:
            print("It took the computer {0} guesses.\nYou win!\n".format(com_guesses))
        play_again = str(input("To play again type 'yes'. To exit type 'no'. \n"))
        if play_again == "yes":
            mainloop()
        if play_again == "no":
            raise SystemExit(0)
    while True:                 #tells program how to handle guesses after the first guess
        guess2 = guess_number(level)
        check_guess(guess2,number)
        num_guesses += 1
        if guess2== number:
            print( "You got it in {0} guesses.".format(num_guesses))
            if num_guesses == com_guesses:
                print("It took the computer {0} guesses too!\nIt's a tie!\n".format(com_guesses))
            if num_guesses > com_guesses:
                print("It took the computer {0} guesses.\nThe computer wins!\n".format((com_guesses)))
            if num_guesses < com_guesses:
                print("It took the computer {0} guesses.\nYou win!\n".format(com_guesses))
            play_again = str(input("To play again type 'yes'. To exit type 'no'. \n"))
            if play_again == "yes":
                mainloop()
            if play_again == "no":
                raise SystemExit(0)
            break





mainloop()
```

Comment: More appropriate for Code Review - http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on [codereview.se]

Answer (score 0):

In `get_number(level)`:

- `elif` could be used for all `if` expressions after the first one. This would make the execution faster because in cases where an expression is true the later expressions must not be evaluated. (The same in `guess_number(level)` and `check_guess(guess,number)`.)
- The `elif` could be made an `else`.
- What is `get_number()` supposed to do? I think you want to write `number = get_number(level)` or you could use a `while` loop for the whole block of statements.

What is the `while` loop in `mainloop()` supposed to do? You implement a repeated execution of the code by calling `mainloop()` within itself. However, I would prefer the `while` loop against your implementation.

Is the beaviour if neither yes or no is input (breaking out of the loop and getting to the end of `mainloop` intended?

Why do you differentiate between the first guess and later guesses? They could be handled with the same code.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! After making this post I realized it is redundant to differentiate between the first guess and subsequent guesses and changed the code to no longer do this.  Also, the purpose of the while loop is to allow multiple guesses to be made without the answer (number) changing.  Calling mainloop() within itself allows a new number to be selected for the next round of the game by returning to the number selection process before re-entering the while loop.  I implemented your suggestion to change the if's to elif's!